# Adding very fast to a ListView from multiple threads

Tags: c#, listview

I am using the following method when adding items to my `ListView`.

I've made sure to have the `ListView` double buffered and tried to optimize everything that I can think of - but no matter what I do the UI is sluggish when adding items rapidly.

I have had this problem for quite some time and scouted around trying to find a solution, but gave up each time because I just wasn't able to fix it. This time I'm hoping to solve this problem. :)

I've though about maybe going with some custom solution? Are there any good ones that can handle "SPEED"? Or is there something I can do with my current code?

Method:

```
private void AddNewItemToListView(string gPR, string rank, string category, string name, string url, string email, string address, string phone, string metadesc, string metakeywords, string mobile, string numbofreviews, string rating, string facebook, string twitter, string googleplus, string linkedin, string sitemap, string siteage, string backlinks, string trafficvalue)
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
        delegate
            {
                string[] row1 = { url, urlSec, address, phone, metadesc, metakeywords, mob, REV, RT, gPR, FB, TW, googleplus, LI, ST, SA, BL, TV };
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

                flatListView1.Items.Add(name).SubItems.AddRange(row1);                               
            }
        ));
}
```

Comment: Does the speed improve if you change `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be able to use the ListView.SuspendLayout() method at the start of the work and then call ListView.ResumeLayout() at the finish? That would speed things up alot, I think. You could also try to resume at regular intervals to get some feedback. For instance by inserting the following code at the indicated position:

```
// Start of work
flatListView1.SuspendLayout();

// Below code inside your delegate

flatListView1.Items.Add(name).SubItems.AddRange(row1);   

if ((flatListView1.Items.Count % 1000) == 0)
{
    // Force a refresh of the list
    flatListView1.ResumeLayout();
    // Turn it off again
    flatListView1.SuspendLayout();         
}

// End of code inside delegate

// Resume layout when adding is finished

flatListView1.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: No, it would just prevent the ListView from updating its UI at every addition, but instead refresh every 1000 items.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Daniel! Saved me this headache :))

Comment: That's nice to hear! The methods are inherited from  `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, so they're also available on other controls that can contain lots of data, like TreeView, ListBox etc.

Comment: This is totally awesome! Am implementing this on all my ListView controls made my app so much more professional :) +++ to you Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly adding to the UI you can add to a list that slowly gets consumed and added to the UI at x items every second.  I've quickly wrote a loose example below but you can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

```
private BlockingCollection queue;

public void Start() 
{
    queue = new BlockingCollection<string[]>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
        while(!queue.IsCompleted) 
        { 
            var item = queue.Take(); 
            //add to listview and control speed 
        } 
    });

    Start.Whatever.Produces.Items();
    //when all items added to queue.
    queue.CompleteAdded();

}

private void AddnewItemToListView(...) 
{
    var row = ...;
    queue.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Hmm that sounds very smart.. how would i accomplish that in code?

Comment: Make sure you use the `ConcurrentBag<T>` if are writing to it from multiple threads.

Comment: @Jacqueline - UI optimization is not a small or insignificant task. You'll probably want to research this topic more thoroughly before asking "how to do it." :)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 year ive come to realize that :) My program runs up-to 500ish threads so UI gets really sluggish when writing to the LW